# MSG Clarification on PidTagInternetCodePage, PidTagMessageCodepage, PidTagStoreSupportMask

Tags: outlook, mapi, msg

The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463900(v=exchg.80).aspx) for the MSG format states

1. [PidTagStoreSupportMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff849785(v=exchg.80).aspx)

> indicates whether string properties within the .msg file are Unicode-encoded or not. STORE_UNICODE_OK Set if the string properties are Unicode-encoded.

2. [PidTagMessageCodepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee124311(v=exchg.80).aspx)

> specifies the code page used to encode the non-Unicode string properties on this Message object

3. [PidTagInternetCodepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179445(v=exchg.80).aspx)

> indicates the code page used for the PidTagBody property or the PidTagBodyHtml property

Based on the above my understanding is that if the unicode mask is set then all String properties are [unicode encoded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee224097(v=sql.105).aspx) i.e UTF-16LE
If the mask is not set then PidTagMessageCodepage is used to decode all String properties in the message.
Based on [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157350(v=exchg.80).aspx) non-unicode and unicode properties cannot exist together.

So, what is the purpose of the PidTagInternetCodepage ? It is used to decode the [body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee158918(v=exchg.80).aspx) or [bodyhtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202050(v=exchg.80).aspx) which have types ptystring.

If a message has the unicode storemask then

Q1. Do we decode the PidTagBody/PidTagBodyHtml using unicode or PidTagInternetCodepage ?

If a message is non-unicode then

Q2. Do we decode PidTagBody/PidTagBodyHtml using PidTagMessageCodepage or PidTagInternetCodepage ?

Q3. Do we use unicode when storemask is set, and when it is not first attempt PidTagInternetCodepage then PidTagMessageCodepage for  PidTagBody/PidTagBodyHtmlit ?

Q4. What do we do if none are present .. default to 1252 ?

Comment: Found some additional information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159376%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PR_BODY is not different from any other string property (such as PR_SUBJECT) - it comes in both PT_STRING8 and PT_UNICODE flavors.

PR_HTML, on the other hand, is PT_BINARY and it stores the data in a binary byte blob. Most HTML bodies includes the charset as a part of the HTML headers, but if it is not present, you will need to use PR_INTERNET_CODEPAGE.

Comment: The question is about PR_BODY_HTML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagbodyhtml-canonical-property which is PT_STRING8 or PT_UNICODE and the documentation linked in the question https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179445(v=exchg.80).aspx states that PR_INTERNET_CODEPAGE is use to encode that

Comment: I have not seen PR_BODY_HTML property used by Outlook since version 2002 in the IMO mode. All the latest versions use PR_HTML. Do you actually see that property in OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI?

Comment: I don't see it in outlook spy. In other tools like MSGViewer or any tool that can view a compound file binary, instead of the PR_HTML (1013102)  i see PR_BODY_HTML (1013001F) and the java library I am using sees the same thing. The msg was test generated, with rtf content, sent as an email and on observing with Outlookspy has html content. The html content in outlookspy in PR_HTML also has a comment tag "converted from rtf/text format" in it.  Is that by outlook spy ? In the other tools the PR_BODY_HTML has the html content without that comment.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagbodyhtml-canonical-property i c now from the docs that pidtagbodyhtml stores content from PidTagBodyContentLocation in html and is probably not what i was looking for